# Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense suggests ScriptEngine for closing script tag

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tags, intellisense

Is there any way to get Visual Studio 2010's Intellisense to not suggest ScriptEngine when you are typing a closing script () tag? When I type the > after script, it replaces it with ScriptEngine and I have to hit undo to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this behavior: [image]

What type of file are you in?

Comment: It only does it on the closing </script> tag, not the opening one. I am editing an ASPX file. http://i.imgur.com/W84Yv.png